What is meant by Mahat-Tattva and Ahamkara as per Samkhya?
In Swami Tapasyananda's Gita there's a chapter where swami ji has explained (from the point of view of samkhya philosophy) the evolutes of Prakriti.
Below is the attached image.
As you can see in the image, from Prakriti comes Mahat-Tattva and Ahamkara. However, certain things are not clear to me.

What is meant by Mahat-Tattva?

What is meant by Ahamkara here that's coming out of Prakriti?
... Is Samkhya speaking of the individual person's ahamkara or the cosmic ahamkara? If it's cosmic ahamkara, then can someone explain to me in detail what this cosmic ahamkara is or how it functions, and whether it is related to the individual jiva's ahamkara?

Also Antah-karana is shown in this image as distinct from the sookshma Jnanendriyas & Karmendriyas.
As far as i know, the antah-karana AKA the empirical transmigratory individual entity, houses not only the manas, buddhi, chitta, ahamkara, but it also houses the sookshma jnanendriyas and karmendriyas, which survives when the physical sheath falls dead. What are your thoughts on this?


Please help me with these three points.
Thank you.


The three questions are:
[What is meant by Mahat-Tattva?]
ANSWER:

Mahat is an important concept of the Sankhya philosophy, also accepted
by Vedanta metaphysics. It is the first product of evolution of
pradhana or prakrti (basic inert matter) comprising the three gunas -
sattva, rajas and tamas. In its cosmic aspect it is 'mahat', the great
germ of this vast world of objects. In its psychological aspect it is
buddhi, the cosmic intellect, from which the individual buddhis are
produced in course of time by further evolution.

A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda
[What is meant by Ahamkara here that's coming out of prakriti? ... Is samkhya speaking of the individual person's ahamkara or the cosmic ahamkara? If it's cosmic ahamkara, then can someone explain to me in detail what this cosmic ahamkara is or how it functions, and whether it is related to the individual jiva's ahamkara?]
ANSWER:

Ahankara (egoism) is that which produces abhimana, the sense of 'I' and 'mine'. According to Sankhyan metaphysics ... ahankara is the
principle of individuation that arises after mahat or buddhi in the
process of evolution from prakrti (nature). It is regarded as a
substance since it is the material cause of other substances like the
mind or the sense-organs. Through its action the different purusas
(individual selves) become endowed each with a separate mental
background. These purusas identify themselves with the acts of prakrti
through ahankara.
At the individual level it makes the purusa feel that he is receiving
the sensations through the senses and the mind, and deciding about
appropriate action, through the intellect.
At the cosmic level, the five senses of cognition (jnanendriyas), the
five organs of action (karmendriyas), the mind (manas) and the five
subtle elements like the earth (tanmatras) are produced out of
ahankara.

A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda
[Also Antah-karana is shown in this image as distinct from the sookshma Jnanendriyas & Karmendriyas. As far as i know, the antah-karana AKA the empirical transmigratory individual entity, houses not only the manas, buddhi, chitta, ahamkara, but it also houses the sookshma jnanendriyas and karmendriyas, which survives when the physical sheath falls dead. What are your thoughts on this?]
ANSWER:

The general name by which mind is known in the Hindu scriptural works
is 'antahkarana', the 'inner (antah) instrument (karana).' Even
though the external sense-organs like the eye or the ear are
functioning, no cognition becomes possible unless the mind is
connected with them. ....
......
This antahkarana functions in four different ways and gets four
different names according to the functions. While functioning as the
receptive and retentive faculty it is called 'citta' or mind-stuff; as
the questioning, doubting and willing faculty, it is called 'manas' or
mind; as the deciding faculty it is called 'buddhi' or intelligence;
and as the identifying faculty which identifies itself with each of
these functions it is called 'ahankara' or the ego.
These words are sometimes used to mean antahkarana or mind as a whole
and sometimes to mean the particular faculty indicated. ...

A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda
Antahkarana is simply a name for the mind.

So, if i understand you correctly, mahat-tattva is the cosmic buddhi, am i right? What is meant by mahat being the great "GERM" of this vast world?

Yes, mahat-tattva is cosmic buddhi. Mahat is called the great germ by the Swami to indicate that the cosmos has emerged from Mahat.

Do sankhya vadis consider this mahat to be like Ishwara, with divine cosmic intelligence? As far as i know, samkhya vadis don't really believe in Ishwara or Brahman, or even if they do, atleast they don't give too much importance to that subject while explaining their philosophy. So, if mahat produces the subtle and gross worlds, then do samkhya vadis see mahat as ishwara? If not, what do they really mean by cosmic intelligence? I mean, in order for cosmic intelligence to exist, shouldn't there be an all-powerful being, which possesses that intelligence?

Mahat is an evolute of Prakrti. The Prakrti of Sankhya is not a material substance nor is it a conscious entity, since purusa is distinguished from it. It gives rise to the five elements of the material universe but also to the psychical. It is the basis of all objective existence. Buddhi or intelligence is a property of the mind, is an evolute of Prakrti and appears to work because of Purusa. So there is no need to bring in Isvara.

The point is that Prakrti supplies the raw materials of the body and the mind. The mind itself is not conscious. A section of the mind appears as buddhi due to the Purusa.

doesn't the brihadarankya upanishad say that ahamkara is the true self?  so any derivative of that would be the small self born of mind...

No. Ahankara is an evolute of Prakrti.

1. Mahat-tattva
Mahat-tattva is intellect or buddhi.
Samkhya Aphorism I.71

महदाख्यं आद्यं कार्यं तन्मनः


mahadākhyaṃ ādyaṃ kāryaṃ tanmanaḥ


The first product [of the Primal Agent, Nature], which is called 'the Great one,' is Mind.


a. 'Mind' (manas). 'Mind' [is so called], because its function is 'thinking' (manana). By 'thinking' is here meant 'judging' (niśchaya). That of which this is the function is 'intellect' (buddhi); and that is the first product, that called 'the Great one' (mahat): such is the meaning.

Aniruddha who wrote the famous commentary on Samkhya Sutras of Kapila has said this -

Sutra 1.71 - The first product is that called the 'great one'; this is the thinking organ.


Commentary - The first product of primitive matter is the 'great' principle or judging organ, [also called] thinking organ, because thinking [is its function].

So, though the sutra used the word 'manah' or mind, it is pointing towards the thinking faculty of mind, known as buddhi or intellect. Thus, the Mahat tattva is intellect.
2. Ahamkara
Sankhya Aphorism I.72

चरमो ऽहङ्कारः


caramo 'haṅkāraḥ


'Self-consciousness' is that which is subsequent [to Mind.]


a. 'Self-consciousness,' the function of which is a conceit [that 'I exist,' 'I do this, that, and the other thing'], is that which is subsequent: that is to say, 'Self-consciousness' is the next after 'the Great one' [§ 71].


b. Since 'Self-consciousness' is that whose function is a conceit [which brings out the Ego, in every case of cognition, the matter of which cognition would, else, have lain dormant in the bosom of Nature, the formless Objective], it therefore follows that the others [among the phenomena of mundane existence,] are effects of this [Self-consciousness];

According to Samkhya, there are innumerable Purushas. When they come in contact with Prakriti, Prakriti starts manifesting. So this is the individual ahamkara Samkhya is talking about.

Samkhya Karika 18: From the individual allotment of birth, death and the Instruments, from non-simultaneous activity (towards the same end), and from the diverse modification of the three Gunas, multitude of Purusas is verily established.

3. Antahkarana

Samkhya Karika 33: The internal Instrument is threefold; the external, tenfold, called the object of the three. The external instrument operates at time present; the internal at all the three times.


Commentary - Called the object of the three; because the external instruments of cognition and action are the channels through which the three internal instruments of Buddhi, Ahamkara and Manas come into contact with, and excercise their functions in regard to the external objects.

Chitta is just another name for Antahkarana. The transmigratory entity is not Antahkarana. The name of the transmigratory entity is Lingadeha or Sukshma Sharira. That is as you rightly said antahkarana plus other things.
4. The image that you attached is wrong
The image that you have attached (the book page) did not show the Samkhya  Tattvas correctly. Here is the corrected version according to Samkhya canonical texts (Samkhya Sutra, Smakhya Karika and Tattva Samasa - the three source books of Kapila's Samkhya Darshana).
Every individual has three components of their mind (chitta), which are manas, buddhi and ahamkara.
There are 25 tattvas (1+7+16+1=25) according to the Samkhya philosophy.

Samkhya Karika 3: Nature (Prakriti), the root (of material forms), is not produced. The Great One (Mahat=Buddhi or Intellect) and the rest (which spring from it) are seven (substances), producing and produced. Sixteen are productions (only). Soul (Purusha) is neither producing nor produced.

Now, the question is what is the sequence they are getting produced? The chart that is shown in the book is wrong. Here is the corrected version.

Samkhya Karika 22: From Prakriti (evolves) Mahat; thence, Ahamkara; and from this, the sixteenfold set; from five, again, among the sixteenfold, the five Elements.


Commentary- The sixteenfold set: that is the eleven Indriyas (mind, five senses, and five organs of action) and the five Tanmatras. From five, etc: that is, from the lower five among the sixteen, that is, the five Tanmatras. Five Elements: viz, Ether, Air, Fire, Water and Earth.

So, you see that your attached image and the book are wrong at so many points. First, five gross elements are not directly produced from ahamkara as shown in your diagram. These are produced from five Tanmatras. Second, From Prkriti arises Buddhi. From Buddhi arises Ahamkara. From Ahamkara arises Manas, five sense organs and five organs of action. So antahkarana is not produced from ahamkara as wrongly depicted in your picture. From ahamkara, just mind is produced (one out of three elements of Antahkarana).
It is really unfortunate that a book represented it in the wrong way.
The correct diagram -

You can check by yourself whether the diagram is right or wrong by cross-checking with the Samkhya Karika 3. Prakriti (1) is not produced; it exists always. So no arrow entered it. The next group of 7 (Buddhi, Ahamkara and Pancha Tanmatras) are both produced and producing as you can see arrows come out of it and arrows enter it. The next group of 16 (Manas, five Gyanendriyas, five Karmendriyas and five Butas) are only produced; no arrows are coming out of them, only arrows entering it. The last one Purusha (1) is neither producing nor produced. It makes up a total of 25 tattvas. The image you pasted cannot be corroborated by the scriptures.
A more detailed and complete diagram of Samkhya's 25 tattvas will be like this -

References -

Samkhya Aphorisms translated by James R Ballantyne
The Samkhya Philosophy (Samkhya Karika) translated by Nandalal Sinha
Aniruddha's commentary translated by Richard Garbe
Samkhya Karika translated by John Davies.


Kindly check the diagram again. The first two products coming out of Prakriti are Mahat tattva & Ahamkara. The third important product is Antah-Karana. If the first two (according to you) are individual mind & individual ego, then why would there be another set of individual mind & individual ego inside the third product of prakriti i.e. antah-karana? Are you getting my point? There cannot be two sets of individual minds and egos ... The first two products of prakriti has to be the cosmic mind/ego in my opinion and the third product antah karana being the individual mind, buddhi, chitta, ego.

@TheCrimsonUniverse Your diagram is wrong. I have shown the right diagram backed by verses from canonical texts.

Didn't get your response. So, when prakriti produces the first two i.e. individual buddhi and individual ahamkara as per your sankhya karika's diagram (a time when the rest, such as manas and 10 indriyas have not yet formed) at what stage does the jiva exists at that point in time? ... The jiva during the formation of the first two, cannot be in sookshma sharira stage, because in order to be a sookshma entity, you need to have all the rest ... So, at what stage does the jiva exists, when only the first two has formed and not the rest, such as manas and 10 indriyas?

"...their "ham-kar" or "Collaborators" who are Lower Ranking divinities"..thus Ahamkara is the higher divine, while we manas fall below the gods

"The word ‘brahman’ is derived from the root ‘bṛṃhati’ meaning ‘great’ "
