What are the Tattvas derived from Prakriti in Sankhya?
What I understood from some online sources was that Prakriti first evolves into Mahat / Buddhi (Intellect). Then from Mahat, the first product is Ahamkara (Ego Sense). Then the Sattva aspect of Ahamkara generates Manas (Instinctive Mind). Then the other twenty sources - Pancha Jnana Indriya, Pancha Karma Indriya, Pancha Tan Matras and Pancha Maha Bhuta further evolve from Sattva and Tamas aspects of Ahamkara.
So Prakriti + Mahat/Buddhi + Ahamkara + Manas + 20 Tattvas = 24 Tattvas.
But then, I saw sources saying that Mahat is Universal Consciousness, also known as Mahat-Buddhi, which creates the Antahkarana (Inner Instruments), which include Buddhi (Intellect), Ahamkara (Ego Sense), Manas (Instinctive Mind) and Chit (Memory). These four along with the other twenty make up 24 Tattvas (Prakriti and Mahat are not counted, as they are seen as primary sources, which have evolved into the other 24).
I see Antahkarana mentioned in the list of Tattvas in Shaiva philosophy. Is this a mix up? Which is the correct answer?

prakrti is "emerging experience", so it not an element itself, that makes 23

and chit=memory, although maybe "conditioned consciousness" is preferred ..

related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/59918/16165
